# Smarty 3 fetch method cut the tail of my html

Tags: fetch, eval, smarty3

I am using `$content = $smarty->fetch('eval:'.$content)`.
The problem is.. it just converts parts of the HTML content, and cut off the remaining HTML code

Anyone can help me, please?

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$value) {
    //echo $key;
    if ( $key != "PHPSESSID" && $key != "__zlcmid" ) {
        $smarty->assign($key,$value);
        //echo " - ".$value;
    }
    //echo "<br>";
}
$subject = $smarty->fetch('eval:'.$subject);
$content = $smarty->fetch('eval:'.$content);
```

$content contain the html template from a database

The form has like over 25 inputs

Below is the template html from mysql database

```
稱謂: {$title} {$name}
地址: {$address}
地區: {$district}
地域: {$area}
電話: {$tel}
電郵: {$email}
推廣: {$promotion}
立邦淨味兒童漆內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior1}
立邦金裝抗甲醛淨味全效(竹炭配方)內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior2}
立邦淨味全效內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior3}
立邦淨味金裝五合一內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior4}
立邦抗甲醛淨味5合1(竹炭配方)內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior5}
立邦第二代超級五合一內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior6}
立邦美得麗M600內牆乳膠漆 - {$interior7}
立邦艷一番光面水性面漆 - {$exterior1}
立邦創意花紋漆 - {$exteriro2}
立邦水凝水性磁漆 - {$wood1}
立邦木晶麗水性木器手掃漆 - {$wood2}
日本漆派樂士手噴漆 - {$wood3}
立邦創意花紋漆 - {$creative}
日本漆派樂士手噴漆 - {$spray}

End
```

Finally after using fetch method
the content behind {$wood3} disappear

Comment: Can you add more context? What do you expect from that method? And can you share some more code?

Comment: I have add more details, sorry.